# Checking if each number in a list is between multiple ranges

Tags: excel

I have a list of numbers (that will be changed weekly) and I also have a list of ranges (that also change weekly). I need to check whether each number falls between each range.

Eg. My list of numbers on the left and my list of ranges on the right.

```
    4               1   3
   10              67   99
   54             120  122
  155
```

So what I need is to return a value if 4 falls between 1-3, then check if it falls between 67-99 and so on. Then return a value if 10 falls between 1-3 or 67-99 etc.

I have tried array and vba but I'm noob and I cant find much in the way of examples for this issue. I have had success with the following nested if;

```
=IF(OR(AND(G2>$L$2,G2<$M$2),AND(G2>$L$3,G2<$M$3),AND(G2>$L$4,G2<$M$4),G2,"")
=IF(OR(AND(G3>$L$2,G3<$M$2),AND(G3>$L$3,G3<$M$3),AND(G3>$L$4,G3<$M$4),G3,"")
```

However, once my number of ranges gets above a certain number it says i have too many characters.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Will.

Comment: Please specify what value you want to return if the number falls into a specific range?

Answer (score 0):

> So what I need is to return a value if 4 falls between 1-3, then check if it falls between 67-99 **and so on**. **Then** return a value if 10 falls between 1-3 or 67-99 etc.

If you want to match each value in col `G` with the list in `L` and `M` then, rearrange the `G` column values in a row as shown below so that you can get the **entire view in one go**.

[image]

Put this formula `=(AND($N$1>L2,$N$1<M2))` in `N2` and drag it down. Similarly put the formula `=(AND($O$1>L2,$O$1<M2))` in `O2` and pull it down and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Siddarth. This works but the number of rows will be changing weekly and your method would be too tedious to do weekly.

Ended up working it out on my own. Pretty simple but took me forever!

```
Sub Subtract_Start()

Set rng1 = Range(Range("G2"), Range("G2").End(xlDown))
Set rng2 = Range(Range("L2"), Range("L2").End(xlDown))


For i = 2 To rng1.Rows.count
For j = 2 To rng2.Rows.count

If Cells(i, "G").Value > Cells(j, "L").Value Then
If Cells(i, "G").Value < Cells(j, "M").Value Then


Cells(i, "G").Copy Cells(i, "J")


End If
End If

Next j

Next i


End Sub
```